# Why do we need more than 24 FPS?

Tags: performance, frame-rate

Many movies (probably, all moovies, except for the most recent ones) have 24 frames per second, and we're quite happy with it.
There is a thing called "Subliminal stimuli" or "Subliminal message" - in Russian it is called simply - "25th frame". It means that somebody inserts some picture (e.g. advertisement) every 25th frame in usual movie and it influences the watcher, though the watcher does not see it. It does not really matter whether it really influences the watcher or not. The important thing - is that we don't see it. For me personally, the most easy way to improve performance in a game - is to limit FPS, usually up to 30 , if a game allows it. So if we're happy with 24 frames per second and we do not see the 25th frame - why do we try to get more and more FPS in games? 60, 70, 100, 120? Why the whole industry is trying to draw frames which we do not see?

Comment: Not sure if that's worth a full blown answer: In the days of the old CRTs 24fps was enough or let's say accepted. The luminescent agent was slow to react and resolution was poor. But today's monitors and tv screens interpolate many frames from the original rate because the LCDs/LEDs or whatever elements they have react fast enough and resolution is high. Just try it out (i assume you can do some basic graphics programming) with the api of your choice, 10, 15, 30, 60, ... fps. You (well, most of us) will realize the difference.

Comment: If you compare a game running on 30 fps, with a game running on 120 fps, there is a difference on how smooth it all looks. I don't know the science behind it, but there's definitely an improvement.

Comment: Low frame rates used to rely on "Persistence of Vision"... Basically we continue to see light for a while after it's gone. That's fine for static scenes but doesn't work so well with movement (it can appear to stutter more, although it's subtle and you usually don't realise until you've seen better). There's also the issue of _when_ to render the frame. Say a frame takes 5ms to render, so we could theoretically present 200 FPS. At 30 FPS that's a frame every 33ms. If you render at the start of that window, your frame is stale. You can't render at the end without predicting render time reliably

Comment: You suggest that a 25th frame can in fact affect a watcher, but because they're not consciously aware of seeing it, it's irrelevant. Are you consciously aware of having seen the other 24 frames individually? You could make the same argument that a 24 FPS video is imperceptibly different from a 23 FPS video, which is imperceptibly different from a 22 FPS video, and so on. But that does not imply that a 24 FPS video is imperceptibly different from a 12 FPS video. Likewise, it does not imply there is no benefit of 50 FPS over 24 FPS.

Comment: [Here is a web application where you can test for yourself how you perceive objects moving with different framerates](http://frames-per-second.appspot.com/).

Comment: By the way, the myth that single frames inserted into a movie can be used to plant subliminal messages in the viewers brain [was debunked](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/382/do-short-pictures-as-subliminal-messages-work).

Comment: Movies very specifically won't move the camera faster than a certain speed because 24 FPS is a severe limitation. Watch the Pulp Fiction scene when they first enter Jack Rabbit Slim's. The camera looks around a lot to give you a sense of the place, but it does so very carefully, as it makes everything a little blurry. Any faster and it would be a mess. For me the difference between 60 and 30 is painfully obvious, and I'm almost 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of frames a human can perceive per second is not a constant number. It depends on a lot of factors.

- Age. Younger people can perceive more FPS than older people. High-fidelity 3d games often target demographics of teenagers and young adults, who have a better animation perception than older people.
- Interactivity. When the viewer does not control the images in real-time (like when watching a movie), then lower FPS are less noticeable than when the viewer controls the perspective in real-time (like in a game). Which is why some games render cutscenes with 30FPS but the game itself with 60FPS and more.
- Type of motion. When watching a static object, then lower FPS are less noticeable than when the object moves around the screen. Objects which move around the screen quickly require a higher framerate to be perceived as fluid than those which move slowly.
- How sharp the images are. More blurry images can get away with slower framerates. Analog film has natural motion blur, which allows lower framerates. 3d rendered animation doesn't, unless you add artificial motion blur as a post-processing filter.
- Brightness, contrast and even the colors used in a scene can be relevant.

Depending on these factors, 30 FPS or even less can be good enough, you might need 60 FPS or some people might even see a difference with 120 FPS.

Here is [a web application](http://frames-per-second.appspot.com/) where you can experiment with different framerates for different kinds of motion and see if you can perceive a difference in quality.

---

And by the way, 24 FPS used to be the traditional framerate for movies, but [there are also movies which run in higher framerates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_frame_rate). Also, many modern TVs have techniques to interpolate between frames to double the framerate of classic 24 FPS movies and tv programs. Most viewers do perceive the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This varies wildly between people and is also affected by the screen technology in use. I spent years gaming at 24 fps on an IBM T221 monitor and perceived as perfectly smooth as long as it was 24 fps, always fps, and never a single frame got dropped. As long as the delay between the frames is perfectly consistent (i.e. you get a frame *every* 1/24 of a second).

I know people who claim that even 60 seems juddery.

Personally, I struggle to tell the difference between a 100% stable 30fps and 60fps, but I can tell a huge difference between different monitors in terms of the amount of motion blur caused by the panel even at a perfectly stable frame rate.

A lot of this comes from the fact that digital display panels suffer from additional lag, motion blur (blanking time is measured grey-to-grey rather than black-to-black, hence why recently there have been technologies like 120Hz displays that insert a completely black frame between two real frames). For example, going from 50Hz to 100Hz will give you an extra 10ms of reaction time, but higher refresh rate screens also have lower lag between receiving the frame and rendering it, which will gain you up to another few 10s of milliseconds, all of which can add up to a measurable competitive gaming advantage.

In terms of persistence of vision, 24 fps is sufficient for perception of fluid motion for most people. Various deficiencies of technology result in requirements being much higher to hide those deficiencies.

Or to put it differently, in a perfect world, a lower refresh rate may well be sufficient for many people, but all technology tends to be built upon many layers of compromises, each of which necessitates higher and higher refresh rates to hide the imperfections.